# Express Can't "findAll" Users By Key, Only By Email

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I have a simple Express/Pug app that is supposed to allow me to search users in a database by "email" and by "key." In this schema, a key is simply a string that each user is assigned. My user model and index model files look like this:

models/index.js:

```
const dbConfig = require("../config/db.config.js");

const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = new Sequelize(dbConfig.DB, dbConfig.USER, dbConfig.PASSWORD, {
  host: dbConfig.HOST,
  dialect: dbConfig.dialect,

  pool: {
    max: dbConfig.pool.max,
    min: dbConfig.pool.min,
    acquire: dbConfig.pool.acquire,
    idle: dbConfig.pool.idle
  }
});

const db = {};

db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
db.sequelize = sequelize;

db.users = require("./users.model.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);

module.exports = db;
```

models/users.model.js:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
  const User = sequelize.define("users", {
    email: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
      validate: {
        isEmail: {
          msg: "Must be a valid email address",
        },
      },
    },
    key: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    wallet_address: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: Sequelize.DATE,
      field: "created_at",
    },
    updatedAt: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        field: "created_at",
      },
  });

  return User;
};
```

My controller file looks like this:

controllers/users.controllers.js:

```
const db = require("../models");
const User = db.users;
const Op = db.Sequelize.Op;

exports.findAll = (req, res) => {
  const email = req.query.email;
  var condition = email ? { email: { [Op.iLike]: `%${email}%` } } : null;
  console.log(email);
  console.log(condition);

  User.findAll({ where: condition })
    .then((data) => {
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message:
          err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving users.",
      });
    });
};

// Create and Save a new User
exports.create = (req, res) => {
  // Validate request
  if (!req.body.email) {
    res.status(400).send({
      message: "Content can not be empty!"
    });
    return;
  }

  // Create a User
  const user = {
    email: req.body.email,
    key: req.body.key,
    wallet_address: req.body.wallet_address
  };

  // Save User in the database
  User.create(user)
    .then(data => {
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message:
          err.message || "Some error occurred while creating the User."
      });
    });
};

exports.findbykey = (req, res) => {
  const key = req.body.key;
  var condition = key ? { key: { [Op.iLike]: `%${key}%` } } : null;
  console.log(key);
  console.log(condition);

  User.findAll({ where: condition })
    .then((data) => {
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message:
          err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving users.",
      });
    });
}
```

My users route looks like this:

routes/users.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const users = require("../controllers/users.controller.js");

/* GET all registered users */
router.get("/registered", users.findAll);

/* GET users by key */
router.get("/specuser", users.findbykey);

/* POST user to database */
router.post("/addsubmit", users.create);


module.exports = router;
```

And my index route file looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const users = require("../controllers/users.controller.js");

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

/* GET user creation page */
router.get('/adduser', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('adduser');
});

module.exports = router;
```

I currently have 2 entry's in my postgres database and the raw output of my db looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "email": "test@example.com",
    "key": "trythis1",
    "wallet_address": "trythisss2",
    "createdAt": "2022-07-09T08:29:02.747Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-07-09T08:29:02.747Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "email": "test2@example.com",
    "key": "trythis1g",
    "wallet_address": "trythisss2g",
    "createdAt": "2022-07-09T13:46:52.261Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-07-09T13:46:52.261Z"
  }
]
```

The `/registered` route works perfectly when I search by email. This is an example of running this route and searching for `test@example.com`.
[image]
Notice above that only the first and correct db entry is displayed

But... when I try to run the `/specuser` route and search by key, the app incorrectly spits out all entries.
[image]

The source of the problem is that `req.body.key` isn't being recognized in `exports.findbykey`. I tried to log `key` and `condition` in my `users.controllers.js` file

```
const key = req.body.key;
var condition = key ? { key: { [Op.iLike]: `%${key}%` } } : null;
console.log(key);
console.log(condition);
```

But I found `undefined` for key and `null` for condition in my terminal. So how can I get this `findbykey` function to properly find the user by key?

Comment: In order to use `req.body`, you must include a body-parsing middleware like [`express.urlencoded({extended: false})`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.urlencoded).

Comment: But why does it work for `findAll` and not `findbykey`?

Comment: `findAll` uses `req.query.email`, which does not require body-parsing.

Comment: That fixed it! If you make this into an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike `findAll`, which uses `req.query.email`, `findbykey` uses `req.body.key`. In order to use `req.body`, you must include a body-parsing middleware like [`express.urlencoded({extended: false})`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.urlencoded).